# C# ASP.NET MVC Can a controller update an element in a view that is currently displayed?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a C# application which displays a basic login form to the user.  There is also a `<div>` on the form with a class of hidden so it does not display when the page is opened.
Once the user enters his/her user ID and password, and clicks on the "Login" button, I execute a javascript that will remove the hidden class from the `<div>` so the contents of the `<div>` is displayed (it contains a literal which says "Please wait..." and displays a spinning graphic).  Control is then passed to a Controller.  The code in the Controller does a lot of background database access so it is a time consuming process (10 - 20 seconds is the norm).  Is there a way for the Controller to update the text literal within the `<div>` so while the database access is happening, I can change the literal to something like "We are almost finished retrieving your information..."?  This way the user does not think the system is hung up.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: No, without page reload it is not possible. As You said, You had to use JS for any dynamic change. You can either fake the labels and upade them based on time interval, or make the logic to write down that data to be able to access it from the other endpoint and call it periodically with JS. Or handle post manually with calling smaller endpoints, doing all the work step by step, each time returning the label?

Comment: @Eatos - Thanks.  When the control is passed to my Controller, and I am executing the backend database processes, can I generate a new thread whereby 1 thread returns the view and another thread continues processing the database? This way, the new view that gets displayed can have a different text message and when the thread that is executing the database process completes, it can redirect to another Controller which will generate a view based on the completion of the database access.

Comment: Once the client gets the view as the result of the controller action the only way to update the view received by the client's browser is to force the browser to hit the server for another view/piece of data returned as a result of another action. This can be only done by calling the endpoint by the user or by code (ajax or such). One way to get what you want is to keep the connection open (WebSocet or SignalR: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-6.0) but I do not recommend it for such case. Feels like very hacky solution to me.